# JQuery UI Draggable + touch punch + touch scroll?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I'm using JQuery UI and [Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) to do some mobile work. I have a vertically scrolling list of items that I need to make draggable.  Obviously this presents a problem.  My idea was to limit dragging to a certain vector and everything else would scroll.  I cannot make it work.

For starters, I'm simply using JQuery's `draggable` parameters to limit dragging strictly to the X axis.

```
$('.menu-item').draggable({
    revert: true,
    helper: 'clone',
    opacity: .75,
    appendTo: 'body',
    axis: 'x'
});
```

This completely disables scroll.  Is there any way to have both functionalities?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are looking for here. Can you provide an example and explain what you couldn't make there?

Comment: I'll work on a demo, but it's only applicable to mobile.  Basically, `.draggable` intercepts the mosuedown/ontouch event and I can no longer scroll the parent container with touch/drag.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? We're facing the same problem for our project currently.

Comment: No, sorry, I had to find another solution.

Comment: What have you ended up doing? I have the same problem.